# Jquery $This Link Get Href

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, this

Ok this is probably a really simple question but i have been searching for about 10 minutes and can't find what works.  I have dynamically generated links on a page which means they all have the dame class.  I want to write a jquery code that that gets the attributes of the link that is clicked by using $this apposed to a class.  Because i many links on the page with the same class if i use class it is triggering all of my links.  My first attempted was this:

```
$(function(){
  $(a).click(function(){
     var page = $(this).attr('href');
     $("#div").load(page);
    return false;
  });
});
```

This does not work. I want it to grab the href of whatever link i click.  If i replace the "a" with a .class it works fine but again i don't want to use class because i have multiple links on the page with same class.  Please help, thank you.

Comment: What is `a` assigned to?

Comment: `$(a)` should be `$('a')`. Assuming here `a` to be anchor tag

Comment: Duh...over site on my part.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the quotes against your selector, due to which it would be considered as a variable. And since the variable is not defined, you would get the error '*a is not defined*'

Change it to the following

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var page = $(this).attr('href');
     $('#div').load(page);
  });
});
```